# Copy Reactions To Discord Messages

Tags: discord, discord-jda

We made a mistake on our Discord server by using a free tool for managing roles. I won't mention it by name. The tool doesn't allow us to edit the original embed that contains all of the emojis and associated roles. As well, Discord doesn't seem to allow you to edit another user's messages, even if you own the server. And that makes good sense.

So what we're left with is creating a new roles message that looks like the old one and adding the reactions to it. However, we don't want everyone to have to go back and redo their reactions since moving the message wouldn't do anything to their existing roles. We still want to be able to see who reacted to the original message, and preferably be able to transfer the original reactions. I would like to know if it is possible to copy the old reactions over to the new message. I kind of think that Discord won't allow it in keeping with the model that you can't do something that a user would do for themselves. But I thought I would ask here first.

Our server management bot is built using JDA and runs on a Linux server.

Comment: It is not possible to react as someone else. I'll suggest you doing your own post, but keep the current post / channel archived somewhere, or simply copy/paste the reactions.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible to transfer over Discord reactions to a different message.

Answer (score -1):

Use better botsite that can edit embed message or bot message
you can create here: *https://botghost.com/?invite=981659393298923621*

*Go to embed builder and try to make a new post there and read how to edit bot post that you posted using this botghost*